# Is there a subquadratic algorithm to partition items into equivalence classes?

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I'm looking for an algorithm. The input is a list of items `x` and an equivalence relation `R` over these items, which evaluates in O(1) time. The output is a partitioning of `x` into equivalence classes.

The straightforward algorithm of checking `R(x[i], x[j])` for all pairs runs in O(N^2). I want to know if it's possible to do better than this in general.

I can keep track of the equivalence classes using a Union-Find in O(Nα(N)) time, so that's not a barrier. I think what would I need is a strategy for checking a subset of pairs.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to do better: **O(Nm)** for m classes is trivially possible.  Let cls[m][*] be a 2D array of items, which we'll partition into `m` classes (the second subscript is a variable index for each class).

```
new_class = 0
for item in all_items
    found = false
    for cls_idx in (0:new_class-1)
        if R(cls[cls_idx][0], item)   // if item is in this class, add it
            found = true
            cls[cls_idx].add(item)

    if not found            // start a new class
        cls[new_class] = item
        new_class += 1
```

You touch each item once.  For each item, you compare against no more than `m` class "founder" elements (the first element of each class).  The complexity depends on the relation of `m` to `N`.  For instance, if `m` is a constant (quantity limit of classes), then this is **O(N)**.